# Error installing ngrok extension in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, ngrok, visual-studio-2022

I have a machine with Windows 10 and VS2019 and VS2022 installed, I have tried to Install the extension through the VS extensions manager, however when I restart I get an error that says: "This extension cannot be installed in any of the currently installed products . " Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This extension was not updated since 18/10/2019 and is not compatible with Visual Studio 2022. Raise an issue with [the extension creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions) but don't hold your breath as it hasn't been touched for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a VS2022 'works on my machine' build of the VSIX -
> https://github.com/timheuer/NgrokExtensions/actions/runs/1685207128
> (artifact download has the vsix)

[Source](http://Here%27s%20a%20VS2022%20%27works%20on%20my%20machine%27%20build%20of%20the%20VSIX%20-%20https://github.com/timheuer/NgrokExtensions/actions/runs/1685207128%20(artifact%20download%20has%20the%20vsix))